# AS3: Line of Sight

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to check whether the object(s) between the point and the object?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this. Looks very good -

http://www.baconandgames.com/2010/02/22/intersection-of-an-ellipse-and-a-line-in-as3/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a sprite, drawing an invisible line (or cone) between the point and the object, and running a hit test?

Comment: hittest create rectangle. hittest with cone or rotated line give wrong result

Comment: OK, I forgot that hitTest got reworked in AS3.  Are you drawing the line on the diagonal or drawing a horizontal line and then rotating it?  Did you try getting the BitmapData for the parties involved and doing a hittest with that (which can do pixel level as long as you set up the transparency properly)?